# bootstrap datepicker with rails content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, content-tag

How do you write the following code using the rails content_tag helper:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this code with content_tag following bellow steps -

Step 1. Go to your application helper files and add below helper method inside application helper file -

```
# app/views/helpers/application_helper.rb

def generate_date_picker_field 
  content_tag :div, class: "input-group date", :data => {:provide => 'datepicker'} do
  concat text_field_tag nil, nil, class: 'form-control', id: nil
  concat content_tag :div, class: "input-group-addon", &-> do
    content_tag :span, nil, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-th'
  end
end
```

end

Step - 2. Call this helper method to your view files. For example -

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body>
 <%= yield %>
 <%= generate_date_picker_field %>
</body>
```

Hope it should work.